# ViewModel for AppShell doesn't retain user data in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I display authenticated user's name and avatar in the flyout of my .NET MAUI app.

I created a view model for the `AppShell` which has a `UserInfo` property that contains all the info about the user. I created a `ContentView` for the `FlyoutHeader` and assigned the `AppShellViewModel` as its view model. I do the same with another `ContentView` I have for the `FlyoutFooter`. The reason for this is because the `AppShell` doesn't let me create view models for my flyout header and footer if they receive services injected through their constructors. So, I decided to create a view model for the `AppShell` and use it for both flyout header and footer.

Because the `AppShell` is initialized even before the user logs in, I use `MessagingCenter` to subscribe to changes to user info.

`AppShellViewModel` looks like this:

```
public partial class AppShellViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   public AppShellViewModel()
   {
      MessagingCenter.Subscribe<User>(this, "userUpdated", (user) => {

         UserInfo = user;
      });
   }

   [ObservableProperty]
   User userInfo;

   [RelayCommand]
   async Task SignOff()
   {
      // Handle user sign off
   }
}
```

This works nicely after initial user login but if the app goes to sleep, it doesn't show user's name or avatar after it wakes up.

In order not to lose the user data, I declared `AppShellViewModel` as a singleton in `MauiProgram` -- see below -- but it looks like the data is still lost once the app falls asleep:

```
...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppShellViewModel>();
...
```

Any suggestions as to how I can retain user info in `AppShellViewModel` so that whether the app falls asleep or not, the user info is always avaiable?

Comment: Declare a static variable, and have it refer to that instance. Not sure if that will stop new one from getting created. If another one shows up (`!ReferenceEquals(newVM, oldStaticVM)`), copy data from old to new. Actually, there should be some way to programmatically create and use a VM, even if you are using Maui's DependencyInjection elsewhere. Then you would have more control. Maybe someone knows a way.

Comment: Just came up with an idea and updated the original post -- see UPDATE section. Any problems with this approach? Seems to be working.

Comment: I do save the user info in SQLite database. The problem was `AppShell` didn't hit `OnAppearing()` no matter what I did. With this approach, I hit the `GetUser()` method after the app wakes up. On the initial login, I hit it too but the database doesn't have user info so it returns null and nothing happens. Not terribly crazy about calling `async` methods from the constructor but I think this approach does it synchronously.

Comment: Instead of updating the question to add code that works, please create "Your Answer" below, with the working code. The result is a Q&A that clearly shows "problem" => "solution", for others in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Re "calling async code from constructor": Its fine to fire off a separate thread from the constructor, imho. It would only be a problem if you tried to do something "synchronous" with it (such as `.Result` to wait for the task to run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to make a "fire and forget" call from the constructor of `AppShellViewModel` which will read the data  from SQLite database.

The code looks like this:

```
public partial class AppShellViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   public AppShellViewModel()
   {

      // This is the "fire and forget" task
      Task.Run(async () => await GetUser());

      MessagingCenter.Subscribe<User>(this, "userUpdated", (user) => {

         UserInfo = user;
      });
   }

   [ObservableProperty]
   User userInfo;

   [RelayCommand]
   async Task SignOff()
   {
      // Handle user sign off
   }

   async Task GetUser()
   {
      var user = await _dbService.GetUser();
      if(user != null)
         UserInfo = user;
   }
}
```

This approach has the following benefits:

1. We hit the constructor of `AppShellViewModel` every time we pull up the `AppShell` which gives us an opportunity to call the database to get user data
2. The most important part of this approach is the "fire and forget" task which has no negative impact on `AppShellViewModel`. We need this approach because we can't make `async` calls from the constructor and making a synchronous call would definitely have a negative impact on the app -- most likely cause a crash.

Comment: Is the call to MessagingCenter.Subscribe necessary here? P.s. if you tag the question with c# then SO will add UI hints to your code